# Bootstrap image logo in the middle of navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a navbar with logo in the middle but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
'http://codepen.io/magg1e/pen/PZwyOp'
```

Any suggestions? Or maybe there's a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap set `img` as block elements so they are not centered as their default `inline` behavior. Add this:

```
.navbar-brand > img{
  display: inline;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVwGrx